# mapping relational database schema to document type definition (DTD)

Tags: xml, database, dtd

Is it possible to map relational database schema to document type definition (DTD) Then start Populating an XML document. I have been given something like the following:

Division(**A**, B, C, D) and other 4 more relations (tables)

I know that if I have xml then I can make the DTD, but in this case the relational database schema has been given. The question was:

"Design a proper DTD for the information given by the above relational database schema. The valid XML documents under this DTD must have a tree structure with as much nesting as possible. The DTD must also capture all the primary key and foreign key constraints."

I am not looking for pure direct answer, but I really want to understand if I can make DTD from the 4 given relations (tables). If it is possible, are there any steps that I need to know.

I have tried to do the xml but the instruction given  ask to make the DTD first then populate an xml file.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to do this automatically, or a methodology for doing it manually?

Comment: If you have a schmea, you can use the xsd.exe tool to create class data in languages CS, VB, JS, or VJS, or CPP.  You can then in CS (c#) or Power Shell use migration to create a database.  Once the class data is populate you can serialize the populated classes and create an XML file.

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay . Yes, I am looking for doing it manually (methodology) I know that it should start with something like this: 
<!ELEMENT Company (A, B, C, D)>

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way the requirement has been expressed indicates that the XML should represent relationships using the XML tree structure where possible, or ID/IDREF relationships otherwise. I think that to get this right, you need to reverse-engineer an entity-relationship model from the SQL database schema, and then find an XML representation of that entity-relationship model - which will involve deciding which relationships to model using XML containment and which to model using ID/IDREF foreign keys.

Good luck: it's an interesting assignment.

You say:

> I have tried to do the xml but the instruction given ask to make the
> DTD first then populate an xml file.

I would never try to write a DTD without first producing a representative XML document to test it against.